# Continuous plotting with seaborn with varying markers based on variable z

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a seaborn lineplot with `sns.relplot` using markers to distinguish between state changes over time, along with some arbitrary value on the y-axis.

**Using the dataset below:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME':['29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719'],
    'DIAGNOSIS':['negative', 'negative', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive', 'negative'],
    'ENTRY_DATE': ['2014-01-23 15:13:54', '2015-03-06 15:57:16', '2016-02-26 14:40:53', '2016-02-26 14:40:53', '2017-11-24 15:20:38', '2020-01-29 13:41:24', '2020-03-30 12:11:24'],
    'CALCULATED_VALUE': [0.456957, 0.468468, 0.865333, 0.896950, 0.920930, 0.767100, 0.835690]
})
df['ENTRY_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ENTRY_DATE, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

|  | NAME | DIAGNOSIS | ENTRY_DATE | CALCULATED_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 29078719 | negative | 2014-01-23 15:13:54 | 0.456957 |
| 1 | 29078719 | negative | 2015-03-06 15:57:16 | 0.468468 |
| 2 | 29078719 | positive | 2016-02-26 14:40:53 | 0.865333 |
| 3 | 29078719 | positive | 2016-02-26 14:40:53 | 0.89695 |
| 4 | 29078719 | positive | 2017-11-24 15:20:38 | 0.92093 |
| 5 | 29078719 | positive | 2020-01-29 13:41:24 | 0.7671 |
| 6 | 29078719 | negative | 2020-03-30 12:11:24 | 0.83569 |

```
sns.relplot(
    data=df,
    x='ENTRY_DATE',
    y='CALCULATED_VALUE',
    kind='line',
    height=8.27,
    aspect=11.7/8.27,
    linewidth=2.5,
    markers=True,
    style='DIAGNOSIS'
)
plt.show()
```

[image: tried]

**Would like to achieve:**

[image: to achieve]

Comment: Seems like you want a single line plot and then a scatterplot with a `style` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** *The data changed in question, and the graph matched output prior to data in the question and images changing. That's why the output in my question does not match the new desired output, but the same code should work with the different data.*

`relplot` is a figure-level plot that isn't great for dynamically plotting in a nuanced way like this. As such, I don't know if you could do such a customized graph with `seaborn`, but you could use `matplotlib` and plot three separate lines depending on what `grp` each line falls in. This is pretty customized, but you could adjust the logic to create the groups, and I have used a combination of the `grp` number as well as using using `shift` to connect the lines and try and match your expected output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME':['29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719'],
    'DIAGNOSIS':['negative', 'negative', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative'],
    'ENTRY_DATE': ['2014-01-23 15:13:54', '2015-03-06 15:57:16', '2016-02-26 14:40:53', '2016-02-26 14:40:53', '2017-11-24 15:20:38', '2017-11-24 15:20:38', '2020-01-29 13:41:24'],
    'CALCULATED_VALUE': [0.456957, 0.468468, 0.865333, 0.896950, 0.920930, 0.833549, 0.767100]
})
df['ENTRY_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ENTRY_DATE, infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.sort_values('ENTRY_DATE')
grp = (df['DIAGNOSIS'] != df['DIAGNOSIS'].shift()).cumsum()
plt.figure(dpi=125)
df1 = df[(grp == 1).shift(2).fillna(True)]
df2 = df[(grp == 2).shift().fillna(False) & (grp == 2)]
df3 = df[(grp == 3).shift(-1).fillna(True)]
plt.plot(df['ENTRY_DATE'], df['CALCULATED_VALUE'], visible=False)
plt.plot(df1['ENTRY_DATE'], df1['CALCULATED_VALUE'], color='red',
         label=df['DIAGNOSIS'].iloc[0])
plt.plot(df2['ENTRY_DATE'], df2['CALCULATED_VALUE'], marker='x', 
         linestyle='dashed', markersize=8, color='red', label=df['DIAGNOSIS'].iloc[2])
plt.plot(df3['ENTRY_DATE'],df3['CALCULATED_VALUE'], color='red')
plt.xlabel('ENTRY_DATE')
plt.ylabel('DIAGNOSIS')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another variation of with the markers. One issue is that the `x` markers and `o` markers will overlap, so you can use the same marker style but a different line style. Otherwisee, you might have to create more lines separting the points to get `x` and `o` markers as you've shown:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME':['29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719','29078719'],
    'DIAGNOSIS':['negative', 'negative', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative'],
    'ENTRY_DATE': ['2014-01-23 15:13:54', '2015-03-06 15:57:16', '2016-02-26 14:40:53', '2016-02-26 14:40:53', '2017-11-24 15:20:38', '2017-11-24 15:20:38', '2020-01-29 13:41:24'],
    'CALCULATED_VALUE': [0.456957, 0.468468, 0.865333, 0.896950, 0.920930, 0.833549, 0.767100]
})
df['ENTRY_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ENTRY_DATE, infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.sort_values('ENTRY_DATE')
grp = (df['DIAGNOSIS'] != df['DIAGNOSIS'].shift()).cumsum()
plt.figure(dpi=125)
df1 = df[(grp == 1).shift(2).fillna(True)]
df2 = df[(grp == 2).shift().fillna(False) & (grp == 2)]
df3 = df[(grp == 3).shift(-1).fillna(True)]
plt.plot(df['ENTRY_DATE'], df['CALCULATED_VALUE'], visible=False)
plt.plot(df1['ENTRY_DATE'], df1['CALCULATED_VALUE'], color='red', marker='o',
         label=df['DIAGNOSIS'].iloc[0])
plt.plot(df2['ENTRY_DATE'], df2['CALCULATED_VALUE'], marker='o', 
         linestyle='dashed', color='red', label=df['DIAGNOSIS'].iloc[2])
plt.plot(df3['ENTRY_DATE'],df3['CALCULATED_VALUE'], color='red', marker='o')
plt.xlabel('ENTRY_DATE')
plt.ylabel('DIAGNOSIS')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice answer but I am trying to scale it to a larger dataset (Up to 4 categories in `DIAGNOSIS`). The dashed lined between the two `positive` points is not really necessary. I just need to show that the points are in a different category. Do you have any suggestions that allow the display of a categorical variable as plot point within a time series in the sns package?
It doesn't have to be shown with markers; it can be any indicator (e.g. thickness of lines).

Comment: @CarlChang I don't think there is anyway you can do this with `seaborn` since it is so customized. With super customized stuff, I think you need to find a way to use the same methodology that I have used but somehow make it more dynamic. The fundamental concept is to separate each line in different groups and plot the lines that way.